# Using "struct" for grouping WebMethods in a WebService?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, asmx, webmethod

**Definition:**
Failed to group functions inside structs or classes but I can not list them on browser.
And getting the WSDL since web methods can not be viewed on browser.

***.asmx file looks like this :**

```
public class myProfile : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
        public struct AddressFunctions
        {           
           //[WebMethod] here
        }
        public struct MembershipFunctions
        {      
           //[WebMethod] here     
        }
}
```

**Aim :**
My approach is, accessing the function in a way that : 
myProfile.AddressFunctions.methodName(); would work.

Is there a way to fix this problem? or 
How do you guys achieve to group web methods inside a web service, for the sake of readability and ease of use.

Answer (score 2):

By surrounding with a struct declaration, you effectively remove those methods out of the ´myProfile´ class. Wrap them into a region, like this:

```
public class myProfile : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    #region ----- Address functions --------------------------------

       //[WebMethod] here

    #endregion

    #region ----- Membership functions -----------------------------

       //[WebMethod] here     

    #endregion
}
```

If you need separation on the protocol level, you should introduce more web service classes.

Comment: my approach is, accessing the function in a way that : 
myProfile.AddressFunctions.methodName(); would work.

Comment: No, that won't work. You can use folders in URL to achieve that. However, you'd rather change your solution to use WCF; there's no good reason to stay with ASMX in new code.

Answer (score 1):

You can only "group" methods by their order within the service.

BTW we're you aware that ASMX is a legacy technology and should not be used for new development? You should use WCF instead.

Also, what do you mean when you say "readability"? Who will be reading it?

Comment: my approach is, accessing the function in a way that : 
myProfile.AddressFunctions.methodName(); would work.

I take readability as a high-prio requirement when I dont want other developers to spend too much of time to trace thru my code.

Comment: It's a web service. Functionality is a lot more important than feng shui.

Comment: Besides, you don't have to put all your methods in one .asmx file. Have addressingfunctions.asmx and shipping functions.asmx. And, again, use WCF.